# How to reduce points per seconds use fabric.js

Tags: javascript

I use fabric.js to make a drawboard , user can free drawing  use brush tools and other users can see the draw path in same time in other device like pc (use socket),  and user can save the draw path to the server and I use `loadJSON` to achieve now I have achieve this two function

Because of `_onMouseMove` function is running 80 times in per second in fabric.js  So I have two problem

1、I send the socket in  _onMouseMove function so the socket will send multi times in per second

2、`loadJSON` will get large data

So I want to reduce the times in per second in order to resolve two problem

I have try to add `throttle` when register mousemove in _initEventListeners

```
 addListener(this.upperCanvasEl, "mousemove",_.throttle(function() {
     this._onMouseMove
 }, 40));
```

but it not working in _onMouseMove function

Answer (score 0):

Throttle works a little bit different than you use it. You first have to create a throttled version of the function that you want to throttle by simply calling the throttle function with the callback and the duration and store the throttled function result in a variable. Then use that result as the event handler. Otherwise you would simply be creating throttled functions every time you listen for the `mousemove` event.

```
const throttledMouseMove = _.throttle(this._onMouseMove, 40);
addListener(this.upperCanvasEl, "mousemove", throttledMouseMove);
```

And if the `this` context has been changed inside the `this._onMouseMove` function, then use `.bind()` to refer `this` to the correct object it should point to.

```
const throttledMouseMove = _.throttle(this._onMouseMove, 40).bind(this);
```